# Build and ajax plugin not work

Tags: plugins, ajax

I have this code on a plugin

```
 function ajaxp_init(){

    /*
    * registro del script
    */

    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); 
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js', false, '' ); 

    //keep jQuery and Prototype compatible 
    $url = get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/plugins/pablowishlist'; 
    wp_register_script( 'jquery_no_conflict', $url . '/pablowishlist.js', array( 'jquery' ), '' );     
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_no_conflict' ); 

    global $post;

    wp_localize_script('jquery_no_conflict','MyAjax', array(
        'postId' => $post->ID,
        'action' => 'ajaxp_add_wishlist'
    ));
    //wp_register_script( 'pablowishlist-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/pablowishlist.js', array( 'jquery' ), '2.2.1', false );
    //wp_register_script('pablowishlist-js', plugins_url('pablowishlist.js',__FILE__), array('jquery')); // funcion de wordpress que registra un código, javascript.

    /*
    * load script
    */
    //wp_enqueue_scripts('jquery');
    //wp_enqueue_scripts('pablowishlist-js');

 }
```

and a JavaScript file in the same directory

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

    $('#ajaxp_add_wishlist').click(function(e){
        //alert('hola');
        $.post(document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', MyAjax, function(response){
            alert(response);
        });
    });
});
```

But when I click in the button `ajaxp_add_wishlist` nothing happens.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You never enqueued the ajax_init in a function.  Also you can use [plugins_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) and split into two functions with a shortcode, like this:

(not tested)

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Ajax Plugin
Description: Plugin for adding ajax
Version: 1.0
*/
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Register Scripts
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajaxp_init' );
function ajaxp_init(){

    /*
    * registro del script
    */

     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

     wp_register_script( 'jfile_general_js', plugins_url('pablowishlist.js', __FILE__));
     wp_enqueue_script('jfile_general_js')

}
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Add shortcode
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
add_shortcode('ajaxplug','jfile_manager');
function jfile_manager() {
        global $post;

        wp_localize_script('jquery_no_conflict','MyAjax', array(
            'postId' => $post->ID,
            'action' => 'ajaxp_add_wishlist'
        ));
}
```